# EF update for large table (4M records) - Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to run an Entity Framework Core (v 2.2.6) update via CLI with `dotnet ef database -v update`

There's a few column drops and adds to a table with 4,000,018 records, and I'm getting the below error when running the update. (also adding a new table with fkey back to the big table)

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

I tried upping the Command Timeout but that doesn't seem to be causing anything to wait longer `dbContext.Database.SetCommandTimeout(900);` but the timeout still happened in like 5-10 seconds.

I also checked my connection string and there's nothing specified there regarding Timeout.

How can I run my database update without hitting the timeout?

Comment: Not sure but you can always generate a SQL Script to update. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#generate-sql-scripts

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft awesome thanks so much David I was able to do that (with FROM <latest>) and run manually without problem... but I could see how this wouldn't work for some people with auto-migrations

Comment: Yep.  It's a good question.